# Sequelize a one-to-many relationship. how to create correctly?

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm learning databases, trying to create a user and his two-factor authentication codes. Where one `User` can have multiple `TwoFa`

And so, there are 2 tables, `User` and `TwoFa`

user.ts

```
export interface IUser {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  twoFa: boolean; // Это флаг, включена ли двухфакторка
}

export interface IUserInstance
  extends Model<IUser, Omit<IUser, "id" | "twoFa">>,
    IUser,
    IDateAt {}

export const User = sequelize.define<IUserInstance>(
  "User",
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    twoFa: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
    },
  }
);
```

twoFa.ts

```
interface ITwoFa {
  id: string;
  ua: string;
}

export interface ITwoFaInstance
  extends Model<ITwoFa, Omit<ITwoFa, "id">>,
    ITwoFa {}

export const TwoFa = sequelize.define<ITwoFaInstance>(
  "TwoFa",
  {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      primaryKey: true,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
    },
    ua: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  }
);
```

Also a file with associations

```
User.hasMany(TwoFa, {
  as: "twoFaCodes",
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
});
TwoFa.belongsTo(User);
await User.sync({ alter: isDev });
await TwoFa.sync({ alter: isDev });
```

Below is a test script for creating `User` and `TwoFa`

```
const user = awaitUser.create({
  login: "someLogin",
  email: "someemail@gmail.com",
  password: await argon2.hash("sfdsfs"),
});
const twoFaCode = await TwoFa.create(
  {
    ua: "dsfjdskfsd",
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
    // @ts-ignore
    User: user // тут ругается тайпскрипт
  },
  {
    include: [User],
  },
);
```

В итоге получаю ошибку

```
  ValidationErrorItem {
      message: 'id must be unique',
      type: 'unique violation',
      path: 'id',
      value: '14218bdb-5fef-4777-bdfd-094551d09ec5',
      origin: 'DB',
      instance: [User],
      validatorKey: 'not_unique',
      validatorName: null,
      validatorArgs: []
    }
```

Actually I have 2 questions now:

1. What did I do wrong in associations?
2. How to create the correct type to create TwoFa so that there is no typescript error and the key is not User but user

Thanks!

**UPD**
if i add in associations `foreignKey: "userId",` and when creating TwoFa `userId: user.id,` then everything will work.
Now the question is, why didn’t it work with include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create a user associated with a new TwoFa instance that has the same primary key value.
If you indicate `include` in `create` that means you want to create a user along with a `TwoFa` record and that's not what you want to get.
If you just want to create a `TwoFa` record and associate it with an existing user then just indicate `UserId` without `include` option:

```js
const twoFaCode = await TwoFa.create(
  {
    ua: "dsfjdskfsd",
    UserId: user.id
  }
);
```

By default you will have a foreign key field name as `ModelName+Id` (UserId) if you don't indicate `foreginKey` option explicitly in associations